# update the application each time there is a new version of Google Play Services

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

Do I need to update the application each time which is using Admob, when there is a new version 
available for Google Play Services ?

If not, is there any explanation on how Google will deploy the updates on Admob ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need update ADmob every time. Now you can use any version from package com.google.android.gms

Answer (score 1):

no need to update admob everytime...